# Connect Python tp PLC via OPC-UA

Tags: python, plc, opc-ua

Sorry for my bad English,
I need to connect,read and write data to plc via opc ua with a python script.
I search some library but i didn't find much.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: do you did any work if yes than please share here it will help other to help you.

Comment: i resolve now, and i find an opc ua lib

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following library:
It has example attached as well.
https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua